# Dead code (Ramda type decelration) breaks Flow

Tags: flowtype, ramda.js

I borrowed this declaration for `tail` function from [Ramda](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/ramda_v0.21.x/flow_v0.28.x-v0.29.x/ramda_v0.21.x.js#L377):

```
declare function tail<T,V:Array<T> | string>(xs: V): V;
```

I have a type `Query` which is basically a `ReaderT Promise` monad:

```js
// @flow

class Query<C, T> {
  run: (config: C) => Promise<T>;
  constructor(runner : (config: C) => Promise<T>) {
    this.run = runner
  }
  bind <U>(f : ((a: T) => Query<C, U>) ) : Query<C, U> {
    return new Query(config => this.run(config).then(x => f(x).run(config)))
  }
  map <U>(f : (a: T) => U) : Query<C, U> {
    return new Query(config => this.run(config).then(f))
  }
}
```

Using this definition Flow correctly fails to type check this expression:

```js
new Query(config => Promise.resolve(config + 1)) // config is {init: number}
.run({init: 2}).then(console.log)
```

[Flow console](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsARQFcBTAJwE8AeAYQBowAVAPjAG9UwxziA7AFxgAFABc4Aa1KCwtAJRgAvGwAK5OAFsAlrlLVWAbi5gMcPrlG8M48sN58+FMEOGm+ULQHMh8pavXauvosCpzc3KIAFjoAdPZKPPyO5MYAvsYARlp8ACZg1ACqLMJQziLC2EJMCspEZFR0jEUKCkIkFDQMYEUcxtzkpKLE5HxgjkjtVK5mHp5+YFGx9tPuXnIxUdLCAB7zUDvry26zcqdpxhrYAA75RSVlFVU1bAWtdR2N3Wxh4QNDI2NSBN6pQVrN5otcHF+GC1htIlsoGduOl0pgzBYwABHBLjd5TY5eeZqTQ6UhxUi4OAwABupFhcwA1GAAIynaF8YTsbJaURCABMqXWm05bipMHJ8E8clQQA)

But when I define a `sequence` function using the declared `tail` function (even if I never call `sequence`), Flow type checks the incorrect expression above without any error:

```js
const sequence = <C> (queries : Array<Query<C, any>>) : Query<C, Array<any>> => {
  if (queries.length == 0) {
    return new Query(t => Promise.resolve([]))
  } else {
    return queries[0].bind(x => sequence(tail(queries)).map(ys => [x].concat(ys)))
  }
}
```

[Flow console](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVATApgYxgQwCcswoBXAOxwBcBLOCsa-WmAHgBUAaANQC4AgoUL4AnpwB8YAD5gAztUK0KAcwkAKAB5y+YHgEpdPANzo8+OXLABFMlkLiAwlzAcpAb1RgwhSrvXUcADWWBS6jvpgALxSAAqEcAC2tHJYkqbeOAwKvjRwhOq+FBT2YP5ZFFC0KuGRMWDxSSlpbpGe3t7UABYpAHRF0T6UJYReYAC+YwBGyhhgbACqGlBlYOrq+LocdVK29k4uS5GRunsObM5gS2DtHcTUZISMJUhnouoVVSrRUt19RR8GF99L1uqEtD9SFoQQDPtV9AixpNvIl8AAHeZLdQrfybVw7K4nGx2c6Xa63bz3R7PLCvEnvOHfep-OT9SiAyrw0FdcFQRHeSaTVAVBTyLAARzsVBIUXmjik6kl9loWCsuiEInEbwuLnwFFEEgkRO1lw1YjYeoNUnqt1oK0VJJVrJgoRU3WisoADG0xpSsA8nmAXsT9gFIY1kql+qq4DAAG5YdQAbQAuvyJmAsDBUjdfT5-dSwEqlKqk56U70ZhQMBD6qkldKAiwYA7laqEb1UWj1KIrPUk5oKxUcPhqD25Aj9EjUEKRdQi4Ng28OV9wwlI1ho3JYwmV9UwABqMAARg7APcylo1F0ACZxiCwRQOduXb14Cop0A)

I should note that Flow correctly identifies the type error if I change the type of `tail` to:

```
declare function tail<T,V:Array<T>>(xs: V): V;
```

(by removing the sum type)

[Flow console](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVATApgYxgQwCcswoBXAOxwBcBLOCsa-WmAHgBUAaANQC4AgoUL4AnpwB8EgBQAPAM58wPAJRKeAbnR588+WACKZLIXEBhLmA4SwAb1RgwhSkunU4AaywUlZlWABeGwAFQjgAW1p5LEktRxwGeWpnGjhCaWcKChMwVwSKKFoAc19-ILBQiKiY6397R0dqAAsogDpMwKdKbMIHMABfPoAjWgoMMDYAVRkoXLBpaXwlDjKbIxNzS2n-fyV10zYLMGm7PsdiajJCRmykfdFpfMKiwJtmtszHhmeVVubvOSvUhyX6fJ7FFSQvqDRzhfAABwm02ks1cSysq2Ou0MxgORxO9QaFyuNywd1xD3BL3K73k7UoXwKEL+TQBUChjkGg1Q+SSYGiAEdjFQSAEJmYbNIhSZaFh9EohCJxPdDpZ8BRRFJsSqjoqxGx1ZqbOVCbRZlLcbK6TBvEVmoExQAGOpnJxYS7XMC3HEbNxAyqRaLtOVwGAANyw0gA2gBdDkDMBYGDRU4NN0exjSwhWqOOmOtEZjQHlQXCnCR5isC0yuWQ1pw+HSUT6cpR2T5-I4fDUJvySEqaGobm86hgAWdb33RnPf1hQNYYPyUMR6fFMAAajAAEY659bKNaNQlAAmfq-f4URlLm2teBFAdAA)

Am I getting something wrong or is it a bug in Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems definitely a bug. I managed to shorten the failing test

```
// @flow

declare function tail<T,V:Array<T> | string>(xs: V): V;

class Query<C, T> {
  run: (config: C) => Promise<T>;
  constructor(runner : (config: C) => Promise<T>) {
    this.run = runner
  }
  chain <U>(f : (a: T) => Query<C, U> ) : void {
  }
}

function wat<C, T>(queries : Array<Query<C, T>>) : void {
  tail(queries)
}

// $ExpectError
new Query(config => Promise.resolve(config + 1)).run({init: 2})
```

Comment: Reported the bug: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2565 (with different snippet a but very similar scenario)